# cq:editConfig not applying outside of parsys

Tags: aem

Cross-post from Adobe Community Forums: http://help-forums.adobe.com/content/adobeforums/en/experience-manager-forum/adobe-experience-manager.topic.html/forum__qugo-we_have_an_imagecom.html

We have an image component, its _cq_editConfig.xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0"
    cq:disableTargeting="{Boolean}true"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:EditConfig">
    <cq:dropTargets jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
        <image
            jcr:primaryType="cq:DropTargetConfig"
            accept="[image/.*]"
            groups="[media]"
            propertyName="./fileReference">
        </image>
    </cq:dropTargets>
</jcr:root>
```

We have a page component ("Blurb") which includes this component as the "featuredImage", as well as a "body" parsys which allows the same component to be used:

```
<div>
  <h1>*Page Title</h1>
  <cq:include path="pageTitle" resourceType="sitename/components/plainText"/>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>*Featured Image</h1>
  <cq:include path="featuredImage" resourceType="sitename/components/image"/>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>*Body</h1>
  <cq:include path="body" resourceType="sitename/components/page/blurb/parsys"/>
</div>
```

If I place a `sitename/components/image` component in the parsys, I can drag an image from the content finder onto the component to set it.  The featuredImage, however, will not accept the drag-n-drop from the content finder (the "not allowed" cursor appears, dropping the image does nothing).  If I open the featureImage's edit dialog, I can drag a content finder image to there.  I am the admin user, there are no permission restrictions.

The same issue applies to text components configured for inline editing.  When the text component is placed in the body parsys (or any parsys), the inline editor works.  When the text component is placed outside of the parsys (Page Title in the example above), the inline editor will not appear.

Interestingly, when I change the Blurb page component use foundation components, the featuredImage drag-n-drop works, but the pageTitle inline editing does not.

```
<div>
  <h1>*Page Title</h1>
  <cq:include path="pageTitle" resourceType="foundation/components/text"/>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>*Featured Image</h1>
  <cq:include path="featuredImage" resourceType="foundation/components/image"/>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>*Body</h1>
  <cq:include path="body" resourceType="sitename/components/page/blurb/parsys"/>
</div>
```

Is this a WCM bug?  Are our components' cq:editConfig definitions missing something?

---

EDIT: This is running on AEM 5.6.1.

Our Image component's .content.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:sling="http://sling.apache.org/jcr/sling/1.0" xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Component"
    jcr:title="Image (Custom)"
    sling:resourceSuperType="foundation/components/image"
    allowedParents="[*/parsys]"
    componentGroup="Site Name Group"/>
```

And dialog.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    xtype="tabpanel">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <advanced
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            path="/apps/sitename/components/image/tab_advanced.infinity.json"
            xtype="cqinclude"/>
        <image
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            path="/apps/sitename/old/components/image/dialog/items/image.infinity.json"
            xtype="cqinclude"/>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

And the cqinclude'd /apps/sitename/components/image/tab_advanced.infinity.json

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
    title="Advanced">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <image
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            collapsed="{Boolean}false"
            collapsible="{Boolean}true"
            title="Image"
            xtype="dialogfieldset">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <title
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    allowBlank="{Boolean}false"
                    fieldDescription="Required Field: If the Alt Text field is left blank, the image title will be used instead. "
                    fieldLabel="Image Title"
                    maxLength="{Long}60"
                    name="./jcr:title"
                    xtype="textfield"/>
                <linkUrl
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldDescription="Optional Field: use the link field to specify where the image ought to link to."
                    fieldLabel="Link to"
                    name="./linkUrl"
                    regex="/^\\S*$/"
                    regexText="Please enter a valid link"
                    xtype="pathfield"/>
                <alt
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldDescription="Optional Field: When text is entered into the Alt text field it will be used instead of the image Title. If the image is used as a link, the Alt text is used for the name of the link. For example &lt;a href=&quot;http://slipsum.com/&quot;> Visit Samuel L. Ipsum&lt;/a>"
                    fieldLabel="Alt Text"
                    maxLength="{Long}100"
                    name="./alt"
                    xtype="textfield"/>
                <description
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldDescription="Optional Field: used to populate the image caption"
                    fieldLabel="Caption"
                    maxLength="{Long}256"
                    name="./jcr:caption"
                    xtype="textarea"/>
            </items>
        </image>
    </items>
</jcr:root>
```

And /apps/sitename/old/components/image/dialog/items/image.infinity.json

```
<image
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
            allowUpload="{Boolean}false"
            ddGroups="[media]"
            fileNameParameter="./fileName"
            fileReferenceParameter="./fileReference"
            name="./file"
            requestSuffix=".img.png"
            title="Image"
            xtype="html5smartimage"/>
```

Sample package for testing (with the text component inline editing) at: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=05420490884931180108

Comment: Please post the .content.xml and the xml dialog definitions of your image component. It's interesting also to know which service pack is installed on your system, because many problems were solved since the initial release of AEM 6.

Comment: I've edited the question to add the additional information.

Comment: I've confirmed with DayCare that this is a known issue in 5.6.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't have the full source I can only guess which problem you are actually experiencing. I see one of the following as the possible reasons:

1. You either do not provide the CQ editor classes as described [here](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/components.html#cq:dropTargets)
2. Your custom parsys is misconfigured, try replacing it with the foundation one.

I tried to reproduce the issue, but didn't succeeded, it's working for me. I created this [sample project](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=13713989666674311003) for you.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  Regarding #1, I've included the _cq_editConfig.xml, which other than omitting the <parameters /> child of <image />, is identical to foundation/components/image.  Regarding #2, the custom parsys is a direct copy of foundation/components/page/parsys.  Additionally, the editConfig works properly inside the parsys, so I don't think the parsys is a problem.  Again, the issue only exists with components that are embedded on the page (children of jcr:content).  Components in the parsys work as expected.  I will try your sample later.

Comment: I've testing your sample project.  As I pointed out the foundation Image component worked properly, as the sample project also demonstrated.  The foundation Text component's inline editing, however, broke under the same conditions.  I have extended the sample project package, adding the Text component; version 1.1 at: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=05420490884931180108  Please have a look and help determine what is different between the two components.

Comment: I extended my sample project with all of your test cases: embeded custom and foundation image and text components with a custom parsys. Everything is working as expected, except of the inline editing of the text component when embeded in a page. This is probably a CQ bug, please report it to daycare if you think that it is important for your project. You can find the latest sample package [here](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=02431914455644884677)

Comment: Thanks d33t.  Though your answer didn't completely answer the question, you last comment confirms my suspicion that there is an AEM bug at fault here.  Marked as correct.

Comment: An additional finding with your updated sample project: when I modified `test/components/image/image.jsp` to remove the placeholder image, it no longer worked for drag-n-drop (not even in the parsys), until an image was set on it.  That differs from our image components, which never accept drag-n-drop when located outside of a parsys.

Comment: Yes this is correct and I described this in my answer (follow the link in the first suggestion). The CQ editor expects special classes in edit mode in order to provide editing functionality.